# javacard jcf file format

Tags: smartcard, javacard

Is there any document where the jcf file format for javacard is described ? it seems to be close to ijc file format ( which itself is roughly a concatenation of the various cap components embedded in a global cap file : header.cat , etc ...) but I can't see precisely how  the format is defined.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

well I'm going to answer to my own question: apparently jcf and bin (ijc) file formats seems completly identical except that jcf as a header who gives -among other things - the length of the data , the rest are the concatenation of the cap components ( seen as bytes streams ) as described in chapter 6 of jvm specs (2.2)

in fact structure of jcf is as follows :

0xC4 0x82 0xLL 0xLL DATA

c482 is the data tag 
0xLLLL is the length of DATA on two unsigned bytes

DATA is the concatenation of the cap components ( Header_component , etc ...)

Comment: As well as answering your own questions, I would advise you to also accept your own answers :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes You are everywhere! I think you invent the _JavaCard_ tag! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The "Interoperability Stepping Stones" document by simalliance.org specifies the interoperable java card format.

The "C4" tag and the BER-encoded length origin in the card specification by globalplatform.org